# Can I run a webserver on an android device?

Tags: web-server

You can [make a Web server on your router](http://nezzen.net/2007/10/15/running-a-web-server-on-a-home-router/) providing that you rewrite its firmware with a free DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.

You can [also run a on a raspberry pi](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver), given that you can run a Web server on any device provided it runs a Linux. Can I run a Web server on an Android device, and if yes, how can I set it up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely! You can either:

- download a ready made one - like [kWS - Android Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws) or
- write your own - [here's some code](https://github.com/bodeme/androidwebserver) to integrate in to your project or just use as is.

Comment: It says. `This app is compatible with all of your devices.` good +1/accept

Answer (score 5):

The book [Pro Android Python with SL4A](http://www.apress.com/9781430235699) comes with some free downloadable source code, you can find it on that official site. In the source code samples there are examples of basic httpserver, and basic ftpserver. Both of those will work on Android devices, I imagine it is also possible to make a more advanced webserver using python, or perhaps even re-purpose one that is already in existence.

Comment: Is python default in Android ?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu To my knowledge it does not come pre-installed on any devices currently. It can be installed via SL4A, or its own standalone apk installer.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/ Yes thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are actually several apps on the Google Play Store. A few of them even have PHP. My personal favorite is [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Till today Oct 22, 2017, there are at least 20 plus application on google play store. I personally develop every web application using my android phone . you can consider using bitweb server or kickweb server . although bitweb server is paid and kickweb server is free. 
Link of kickweb server 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nokshaserver

Bit web server :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb